# On refresh of browser for angular application, i18n folder problem

Tags: angular, internationalization, page-refresh, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I am running the application through npm run watch which starts node server in a seperate port and angular application in different port. The assets folder is also there which contains i18n folder for language implementation and is inside src folder. I am having en.json and fr.json files inside i18n folder, which I use through ngx-translate module. When I refresh the browser, the language is not being rendered properly. I am using setdefaultlang as en but on refresh the keys of en.json comes instead of values of keys.But when I navigate it renders fine. What can be the problem or what should I do?

Comment: What does `the language is not being rendered properly` mean?

Comment: I am having en.json as the file inside i18n folder. When I refresh, the keys of the json are being displayed instead of the values in json file. But when I navigate, it is resolved. On refresh only it happens again and again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the json file has not yet reached your application.

Check [git issue here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader/issues/59). There is the same problem. Then the json comes to your application and so the transations are available.

The fix from redirect can be found [here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/517#issuecomment-299637956)

Basically it's the following:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
    deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
    multi: true
  }
]
```

And define factory function appInitializerFactory upper in the same file:

```
import { Injector, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LOCATION_INITIALIZED } from '@angular/common';

export function appInitializerFactory(translate: TranslateService, injector: Injector) {
  return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
    const locationInitialized = injector.get(LOCATION_INITIALIZED, Promise.resolve(null));
    locationInitialized.then(() => {
      const langToSet = 'en-GB'
      translate.setDefaultLang('en-US');
      translate.use(langToSet).subscribe(() => {
        console.info(`Successfully initialized '${langToSet}' language.'`);
      }, err => {
        console.error(`Problem with '${langToSet}' language initialization.'`);
      }, () => {
        resolve(null);
      });
    });
  });
}
```